# Find deepest path, iterate outwards

Tags: javascript

I have an object, which has multiple children (this object is a serialized MongoDB record)

```
{
  _id: '5881f6564d56a24f09562d9e',
  key: 'value',
  child: {
    _id: '5882211a010ea9725a3efdd1',
    key: 'value2',
    param: 'param',
    nested: {
      _id: '588221592eb1530d6fcc252a',
      arr: [ '588221b83f0f833ba132b670', '588224490a15d836d1ba56e4' ]
    }
  },
  another: {
    _id: '58822c4e48db7912655b3419',
    param: 'value'
  }
}
```

Before using this object in my application, I need to pass it through a function.

```
function processData(value) {
  // do stuff
  return value
}
```

However, this function (not controlled by me) doesn't support nested documents. To correctly process the object, it must start with the deepest nested document, replace it with the return value, then process the next level etc.

A 'document', is an object which has the key `_id`. There may be other objects *without* `_id`, these do not need to be processed. Therefore, it needs to be processed in the following order:

```
obj.child.nested = processData(obj.child.nested)
obj.child = processData(obj.child)
obj.another = processData(obj.another)
obj = processData(obj)
```

The order only matters for objects which have nested children (for example, `obj.another` could be processed before `obj.child`, as long as `obj.child.nested` was processed before `obj.child`).

This is what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/nenuvuwiwa/edit?js,console

Comment: The question is not clear.

Comment: I have a function, `processData`, which needs to be run on each document, starting with the deepest nested, then the parent etc.

Comment: That's not a question, it's a statement.  I've looked at your code it seems right. [Depth-first algo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: Previously it wasn't working, but I think I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using:

```
function processData(obj) {
  // Placeholder function to indicate it has
  // been processed (in reality sets a load of
  // prototype functions etc)
  obj.processed = true;
  return obj;
}

function processDoc(doc) {
  for (key in doc) {
    var val = doc[key];
    if (val.hasOwnProperty('_id')) {
      val = processDoc(val);
      val = processData(val)
    }
  }

  return doc;
}

var res = processDoc(obj)
```